# mysqld - master to slave replication using rsync innodb, sequence number issues

Tags: freebsd, rsync, mysql-replication

I've read several of the related topics posted here, but I have not been able to avoid this innodb error.

The steps I've taken to replicate data from a Slackware server - 5.5.27-log (S) to a FreeBSD slave -  5.5.21-log (F) were these:

1. (S) `flush tables with read lock;`
2. (S) in another terminal `show master status;`
3. (S) stop mysqld via command line in third terminal;
4. (F) while both servers are stopped, `rsync` mysql datadir from (S), excluding master.info, mysql-bin and relay-* files; Also tried `rsync` of all files;
5. (F) start mysqld (skip-slave)

> 121018 12:03:29  InnoDB: Error: page 7 log sequence number
>   456388912904 InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence
>   number 453905468629. InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may
>   have copied the InnoDB InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log
>   files. See InnoDB:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
>   InnoDB: for more information.

This kind of error happens for a lot of tables.

I know I can use `dump`, but the database is large, ca. 70GB and the systems are slow (old), so would like to get this replication to work with data transfer.

What should I try to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use Percona's hot backup utility [Xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/).